# ERROR: function lastvar() does not exist

Tags: function, triggers, plpgsql, postgresql-8.4

I'm having problems with [LASTVAL()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-sequence.html) function. I have a trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema_name.function_name() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
  $BODY$
  DECLARE
    registry_id bigint;
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO schema_name.table_name(column1, column2) VALUES (value1, value2);
    SELECT LASTVAR() INTO registry_id;
    ...
```

When the Trigger is fired  I get the error:

```
ERROR:  function lastvar() does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT LASTVAR()
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  SELECT LASTVAR()
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "function_name" line 5 at SQL statement
```

The table has a PK column with a SEQUENCE as a DEFAULT value:

```
...
table_name_id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('table_name_seq'::regclass),
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote LASTVAR() not LASTVAL()  (**R** instead of **L**).

Comment: Thanks man, I was looking for 15 minutes why this function does exists. I can't believe I was wrong in that way.